# viewing an image like a binary image with cv2 module in python (going in loop)

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7

I try again to do better my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349550/convert-image-in-a-binary-image-with-cv2-module-in-python)

In this code (it's a little bit changed from the first ) I can easily work with my converted binary image , extracting contours, calculating areas.. but it's not again possible to  execute this code line: `cv2.imshow('gray_image',imgray)`.

it show me a total grey window and that's all. I have to quit python because goes in loop.

```
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0) 
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print('oggetti trovati')
print(len(contours))
cnt = contours[0]
print(len(cnt))
cv2.imshow('gray_image',imgray)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Just wonder if you have cv2.waitKey() after cv2.imshow(..)?

Comment: Why now it's work? I try similar work with scikit-image and matplotlib.pyplot and is not necessary!  It cannot execute code showing image and execute other code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you need to add `cv2.waitKey()` after `cv2.imshow('gray_image',imgray)`. This function is for handling any window event like creating or showing an image in OpenCV.